# MonoDevelop: How to auto complete parameters when typing Method name

Tags: unity-game-engine, autocomplete, monodevelop

I'm trying to increase my speed of typing code in a Unity project, and finding a big hole in MonoDevelop.

If I have a method like:

```
void Foo(float x, float y, float, z) {
    //
}
```

When I start typing

```
Fo
```

I want it to autofill with:

```
Foo(x,y,z)
```

with the x, y, and z, highlighted green.

Currently, it only autofills with

```
Foo
```

I would like functionality like what happens when you type for and hit tab twice, where it autofills:

```
for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {

}
```

with max highlighted in green.

I feel like there should be a built in way to do this, but I can't find anything here or on the web. I know for Java in eclipse it has similar functionality to what I want here.

EDIT: Based on a more refined search from the answer below, I was able to confirm that it doesn't seem like you can do this in MonoDevelop. However, this search revealed that Microsoft just released Visual Studio for Mac, which runs super nicely with Unity and has much better code completion features compared to monodevelop. It still doesn't fill in the parameters, but it at least gives you a little popup window guiding you through which ones you need and what type they are. A huge improvement to say the least. After playing around with it for literally 5 minutes, I'm already prepared to scrap MonoDevelop entirely. The nice thing is the interface is basically identical, just seems like a much more polished and modern version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for`+tab+tab is a [Code Snippet](https://mhut.ch/journal/2011/02/monodevelop_tips_code_snippets) that has a whole syntax devoted to typing short things and getting long ones. The `for` syntax is generally unchanged throughout and so it's easy to write a snippet to cover the general use-case.

Methods are not typically in this category of autocompletion, as the number, type, and name of the paramters will change depending on what method is being completed, and so behavior varies by IDE. Eclipse does the best job I've ever seen, even going so far as to make an educated guess as to *which* variables available in the current scope would be appropriate as parameters! Its not always right (eg. I've gotten something like `Translate(xpos, xpos, xpos)` before, when `Translate(_x, _y, _z)` would have been better).

How, and if, you can get Monodevelop to autocomplete method parameters will likely revolve around these snippets. I don't use MD myself so you'll have to dig into the documentation on making your own snippets, but I suspect it won't be possible (based on my own experience reading the snippets docs for Visual Studio).

Comment: Hmm that’s sad. I leaned to code with eclipse and I guess I got spoiled.

Comment: @AdamB You're not the only one spoiled by Eclipse. I learned to code in things little better than Notepad and so didn't pick up any good habits. Eclipse changed all that for me.

Comment: Using the vocabulary in your answer I was able to do a more refined search. You are correct it seems, this is not possible currently for mlnodevelop. What I DID find though is that Microsoft just released Visual Studio for Mac, which runs super nicely with unity and has much better code completion features compared to monodevelop. It still doesn't fill in the parameters, but it at least gives you a little popup window guiding you through which ones you need and what type they are. A huge improvement to say the least. I'll edit my question with this info.

Comment: @AdamB glad I was able to help at least a little bit! Code snippets are a thing I only learned about myself pretty recently (I set up two for Debug.Log, one of which uses the fully qualified name rather than an import).